# Azure Active Directory silent SSO (token retrieval) for client application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I have a client application and I would like to examine the azure ad token claims. By client application, I am talking about an executable that runs on a Windows 10 desktop or UWP application which runs in the user's context.

I have tried:

```
var authenticationContext =
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");

var userCredential = new UserCredential();

var result = await authenticationContext
    .AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
        "https://mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/myguid",
        userCredential);
```

This fails with `password_required_for_managed_user`.

The available documentation claims this approach uses Kerberos, which if true, Azure ADd does not support Kerberos, so it would fail.

```
var _publicClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(clientId);
var user = new ApplicationUser {
    DisplayableId = upn,
    Identifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    // other fields can be null
};

var authenticationResult =
    await _publicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, user);
```

Throws `MsalUiRequiredException (no token in cache)`.

This no longer uses ADAL, it uses a different implementation of `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`:

```
var authContext =
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.TokenCache.DefaultShared);

var result =
    await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", upn);
```

This returns the same `MsalUiRequiredException`

I am at a loss. For a web application, there will be a cookie in the browser cache and I can perform silent SSO using the standard runtime.

Do I have to embed a web server in my application to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

`AcquireTokenSilentAsync` uses an existing `refresh_token` to obtain an updated `access_token`. Since you haven't obtained a token yet, it is failing (thus the "no token in cache" error).

You need to provide a fallback to handle cases where you don't have a valid `refresh_token` available:

```
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read", "mail.read" };
try 
{
    authResult = await App
        .PublicClientApp
        .AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
            scopes, 
            App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
} 
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex) 
{
    // MSAL couldn't get the token silently, so go through the interactive process
    authResult = await App
        .PublicClientApp
        .AcquireTokenAsync(scopes);
}
```

There are also walkthroughs for setting this up for both classic and UWP apps:

- [Windows Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-windesktop)
- [Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-uwp-v2)

Comment: The goal is for the operation to be silent. I am aware of the AcquireTokenAsync fallback, however then it's no longer silent. I know there is a token on the machine in the browser cookie store, and possibly in other places, looking for the correct API to retrieve that

Comment: OAuth doesn't work that way. Unless you have a token for your app, in the current session, then you don't have a token to silently refresh.

Comment: In a silent SSO scenario, I can go from one web site to the other, and I will not be prompted again for authentication at the second site. That seems to indicate that's indeed possible. Furthermore, I have set up a simple web site where that works as well. The site receives the token without further user input using it's own app id. There's also an (undocumented) API in Windows that does the same.

Comment: If this were a web site then yes, it could be nearly silent (technically it redirects to the auth endpoint but since you're already signed in it immediately redirects the user back). This works because the cookie is owned by the auth endpoint, not your app. Since both apps share the same auth endpoint, it uses the existing auth cookie (please keep in mind this is a gross simplification of the process). With a native app, you don't have any cookies. The only app _is_ your app, so the only tokens it has are the tokens it has retrieved itself. Your app cannot reuse data from a browser's sandbox.

Comment: Also keep in mind that every SSO architecture _has a fallback stratagy_. Without one you would leave the user high-and-dry if/when the SSO process fails.